# how to fix "Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error" error

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to android and I am making an activity that has two spinners that populate their drop down items from JSONObjects received from two separate API calls. For some reason i am getting this error. I don't know why I am getting this error or how to fix it. Can anyone please shed some light on it? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!! this is my code:

```
public class AddPropertyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView selectCity;
private static final String TAG = RegisterUserActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private JSONObject jsonObject;
private JSONArray jsonArray;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private MyProperty mMyProperty;
private ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();
private ArrayList<City> locations = new ArrayList<City>();
private ArrayList<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> locationNames = new ArrayList<String>();

private String selectedCity="lahore";
private String selectedLocation="";
private int count=0;
private Spinner citySpinner;
private Spinner locationSpinner;
private DownloadJSON task1;
private DownloadJSON task2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_property);
    Log.e(TAG, "Add property Activity Created");
    mMyProperty = new MyProperty();
    selectCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSelectCity);
    citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
    locationSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_loc_spinner);
    task1 = new DownloadJSON("http://xyz", 1);
    task1.execute();

    task2 = new DownloadJSON("http://xxx" + selectedCity,2 );
    task2.execute();
}

private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private String mURL = "";
    private int choice;

    public DownloadJSON( String URL, int ch) {
        mURL=URL;
        choice=ch;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        jsonObject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(mURL);

        if (mURL.equals("http://xyz")) {

            try {
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                Log.d(TAG, "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    City mCity = new City();
                    mCity.setName(jsonObject.optString("locationTitle"));
                    mCity.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    locations.add(mCity);
                    locationNames.add(jsonObject.optString("locationTitle"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught"+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {

            try {
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                Log.i(TAG, "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.e(TAG, "beep!");

                    City mCity = new City();
                    mCity.setName(jsonObject.optString("title"));
                    mCity.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    cities.add(mCity);
                    cityNames.add(jsonObject.optString("title"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, "exception caught!"+ e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        if (choice==2) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Spinner2 Created");

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddPropertyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, locationNames);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            locationSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            locationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "listener 2 called");
                    mMyProperty.setLocationId(locations.get(position).getId());
                    selectedLocation = locationNames.get(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected: " + selectedLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }

            });
        } else if (choice==1) {

            Log.e(TAG, "City Spinner Created");
            citySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddPropertyActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    cityNames));

            citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "listener called");
                    mMyProperty.setCity(cityNames.get(position));
                    selectedCity = cities.get(position).getName();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected: " + selectedCity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }

    }
}}
```

the error stack i am receiveing is as follows:

```
12/19 01:46:51: Launching app
$ adb push D:\AndroidProjects\Homie\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.teksify.homie
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.teksify.homie"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.teksify.homie
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.teksify.homie/com.teksify.homie.Activities.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 13200 on device samsung-sm_g900w8-0e5df62e
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.teksify.homie-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.teksify.homie rsrc of package null
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.teksify.homie-2/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.teksify.homie, real application class is null.
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.teksify.homie-2/lib/arm
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.teksify.homie-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.teksify.homie rsrc of package null
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.teksify.homie-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.teksify.homie rsrc of package null
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{6d7d821 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ia10634f51b)
          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.29.00.00
          Build Date: 01/28/16 Thu
          Local Branch: ss
          Remote Branch: 
          Local Patches: 
          Reconstruct Branch: 
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x9e53a7c4
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
E/ClipboardServiceEx: clipEx is android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@7039d00
E/ClipboardServiceEx: clipEx has text data : false
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3df022b time:198322914
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 885) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 885) or=1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: The input has been finished in ImeInputStage.
D/ViewRootImpl: The input has been finished in ImeInputStage.
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.teksify.homie time:198328171
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.teksify.homie-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.teksify.homie rsrc of package null
E/RegisterUserActivity: Add property Activity Created
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b419b60 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
I/System.out: Thread-36942(ApacheHTTPLog):Reading from variable values from setDefaultValuesToVariables
I/System.out: Thread-36942(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: Thread-36942(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
I/System.out: Thread-36942(ApacheHTTPLog):getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
I/System.out: Thread-36942(ApacheHTTPLog):Smart Bonding Setting is false
I/System.out: Thread-36942(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Setting is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@f5b1363 time:198328370
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{85ced8e token=android.os.BinderProxy@3df022b {com.teksify.homie/com.teksify.homie.Activities.LoginActivity}} show : false
I/System.out: AsyncTask #2 calls detatch()
I/RegisterUserActivity: Number of entries 1
E/RegisterUserActivity: beep!
E/RegisterUserActivity: City Spinner Created
E/RegisterUserActivity: listener called

                    [ 12-19 01:47:20.834 13200:14034 W/         ]
                    Unable to open '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': No such file or directory
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error
I/System.out: Thread-36943(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: Thread-36943(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
I/System.out: Thread-36943(ApacheHTTPLog):getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
I/System.out: Thread-36943(ApacheHTTPLog):Smart Bonding Setting is false
I/System.out: Thread-36943(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Setting is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{caa0fa7 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #10203a7 android:id/toast_layout_root}
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
I/System.out: AsyncTask #3 calls detatch()
D/RegisterUserActivity: Number of entries 449
E/RegisterUserActivity: Spinner2 Created
E/RegisterUserActivity: listener 2 called
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{8b4f7fd V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #10203a7 android:id/toast_layout_root}
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode     (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@cfe41ec
E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@8e029b5
E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@8e029b5
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{f6e13bb V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{75c27fa V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
E/RegisterUserActivity: listener 2 called
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{e13f2e4 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #10203a7 android:id/toast_layout_root}
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x9ce75380 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle 0x9cc1a090
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2d8134d token=android.os.BinderProxy@f5b1363 {com.teksify.homie/com.teksify.homie.Activities.AddPropertyActivity}} show : true
Application terminated.
```

LogCat

```
12-19 01:47:19.484 13200-13200/com.teksify.homie E/RegisterUserActivity: Add property Activity Created
12-19 01:47:20.774 13200-13996/com.teksify.homie E/RegisterUserActivity: beep!
12-19 01:47:20.774 13200-13200/com.teksify.homie E/RegisterUserActivity: City Spinner Created
12-19 01:47:20.814 13200-13200/com.teksify.homie E/RegisterUserActivity: listener called

                                                                     [ 12-19     01:47:20.834 13200:14034 W/         ]
                                                                     Unable to open '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': No such file or directory
12-19 01:47:21.014 13200-13200/com.teksify.homie E/RegisterUserActivity: Spinner2 Created
12-19 01:47:21.044 13200-13200/com.teksify.homie E/RegisterUserActivity: listener 2 called
12-19 01:47:29.034 13200-13200/com.teksify.homie E/RegisterUserActivity: listener 2 called`
```

Comment: Nothing from that LogCat has anything to do with this activity.

Comment: I pasted this erro stack from the run terminal window but following error is shown in the activitys logcat as well `code`Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar': I/O Error

Comment: That is not related to this activity. If you are crashing, you should be looking for a Java stack trace in LogCat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: ok. so i edited my post to show LogCat. Also, the app doesn't crash but I am consistently getting this error.

Comment: "the app doesn't crash" -- then what is your problem? That is a warning, not an error, and I see no evidence that it is an actual issue and that it relates to your app. There will be **many, many messages** in LogCat, and the vast majority have nothing to do with your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I also see this warning in my work.  Agree it's not a problem, but still wondering what is provoking the warning.  I'm not knowingly referencing anything in com.qti.location namespace ...

Comment: Same thing with my app, I see it after sending email, I use three jar file as a library to send email, the three files are: activation.jar, additionnal.jar and mail.jar. This warning could be produced by one of these files????

Comment: I have the some error. Is there any common solution?